# What are contemporary Non English language and Continental sources in philosophy of mind?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-mind, continental-philosophy, analytic-philosophy

It just came to me that all of the contemporary sources on philosophy of mind that I have been reading (Dennett, Nagel, Churchland, Chalmers, Searle, Hofstadter, Jackson) are all writing in English, and write mostly in the Analytic style.

- Is there something inherently analytic about the philosophy of mind?
- Or are there many Continental and/or non-English language philosophy of mind sources (And am I just biased by my linguistic preferences) ?
- References and links would be nice.

Comment: My sense as someone whose work is not in phil. mind is that if you do phil. mind in the late 20th or early 21s century you do it in English regardless of your native tongue.

Comment: @virmaior I was about to include that in my question (i.e. is it like contemporary physics or math, where English is the lingua franca). But then I noticed that all of the names I mentioned were native English speakers (with the exception of Nagel, who was US educated from a relatively young age).

Comment: In french, there is this for example. (analytic): http://www.amazon.fr/Le-corps-lesprit-causalit%C3%A9-mentale/dp/2711624994 I have the impression that "philosophy of mind" is a term used in the analytic tradition only.

Comment: @quen_tin "Restant dans un cadre physicaliste, il propose une solution qui, faisant appel à l'ontologie des propriétés particulières ou tropes, rompt à la fois avec l'ontologie cartésienne et avec la thèse contemporaine du physicalisme non réductionniste." That actually sounds very interesting.

Comment: @AlexanderSKing he is teaching at my university and also has a blog if you're interested (and if you read french) francoisloth.com/ :-)

Comment: @quen_tin merci pour l'info.

Comment: @virmaior I hope you are not serious, of course different countries have their avenues of publication in their native languages, and theses are not always written in English either. Original work in all areas of philosophy is still published in many languages. This is not to say that English is not the Lingua franca of modern science.

Comment: @Johannes I did my PhD in CS in Japan, and we all had to publish our papers in English, even those who wrote their thesis in Japanese. Once you got a research or faculty position, you were free to publish only in Japanese if you wanted to, but no one was going to take you seriously and you weren't going to make it far in academia.

Comment: @Alexander S King I don't deny that usually you have to publish in English if you want to advance in academia. My point was that original work is still published in other languages. For example, just yesterday I got 300 pages of reviewed articles in my native language in mail, and just looking at the table of contents there is at least one paper on philosophy of mind by a philosopher who has an article in the SEP.

Comment: @Johannes Great! Can you provide me with a ref then?

Comment: @Alexander S King I try to remain unidentifiable at the moment (you probably would not speak the small European language in question), but I'm sure you can find examples through here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_philosophy_journals.

Comment: @Johannes I'm completely serious for much the reason that Alexander suggests. I didn't deny original work of all sorts in philosophy could be published in other languages. As I stated, my sense, i.e. my impression, is that phil. mind is basically a sub-discipline done in English.  There's a bias towards this in all analytic philosophy, but it seems strongest in logic. The logicians at the university down the road all speak English and write their article mostly in English (which is exceptional for philosophers more generally in Japan). Phil. history seems to have the least English-bias.

Comment: I guess I should clarify this isn't to say that authors cannot *also* publish in their own languages but merely to say that they need to put articles out in English if they want to make central contributions to the discipline. (A contributing factor may be that most analytic PhDs in the US no longer have to do a foreign language)

Comment: @virmaior I hear you there is language bias across the board (I am personally unsure phil. of mind is a special case). By the way the link I provided was not that good, it's more useful to look at the list of journals on Philosopher's index (http://philindex.org/scope/journal-coverage/).

Answer (score 2):

Two sources from Germany:

- Roth, Gerhard: Das Gehirn und seine Wirklichkeit.
  [http://www.amazon.com/Das-Gehirn-Seine-Wirklichkeit-German/dp/351828875X/ref=sr_1_6?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1450336783&sr=1-6&keywords=Gehirn](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/351828875X)

Roth is a German philosopher and biologist. His book, backed up by neuroscience, develops a constructivist epistemology.

- Metzinger, Thomas: Being No One.
  [http://www.amazon.com/Being-No-One-Self-Model-Subjectivity/dp/0262633086/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1450336891&sr=1-2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0262633086)

Metzinger is a German philospher. In his book he develops a philosophical theory about our internal, centered world model. The book is challenging.

Comment: Do you have any links to English abstracts or translations of Roth?

Comment: @Alexander Unfortunately Roth's book has not been translated to English. Possibly you can contact him by info@ans-roth.com and ask for some English publications linked to the philosophical content of this book. Roth has published on neuroscience in English, but most of his thoughts from philosophy of mind are published in German.